# Primefaces focus form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, focus, selectoneradio

```
<p:inputText value="#{bmiCalculatorBean.height}" update="@form" id="height">
                            <p:ajax update="@form" />
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="0" />
</p:inputText>


<p:inputText value="#{bmiCalculatorBean.weight}" update="@form" id="weight">
                            <p:ajax update="@form" />
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="0" />
</p:inputText>
```

I have a problem where after I enter a value into the first inputText and click on the "weight" inputText after a short delay the focus is lost and you need to click on the input box again.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `update="@form"` and expected behavior.

In general, just do not update parts which do not need to be updated and update *only* those which really need to be updated. E.g. only the result calculated so far and the `<h|p:message>` of the current input:

```
<p:ajax update="calculatedResult currentInput_message" />
```

True, this may end up in a boilerplate of IDs in `update` attribute in large forms. The [PrimeFaces Selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) (PFS, supporting jQuery selector syntax in JSF selectors) may then help a lot in this.